# JS script to go through thousands of SVG path elements, compare name, id and change their values conditionally

Tags: javascript, svg, interactive

I have an SVG file with over 5000 `<path/>` elements, the elements come with `Name` and non-sequential `Id`. I need every ID to be the same as the name of each path since they represent counties and other regions and also wish to have the same string inside a `displayName()`.

The code shown here is a simplification of the `<path/>` element and what it currently has.

I have tried manually changing these values manually but its just not practical especially with thousands of these, it would take me weeks.

The onmouseover is part of the SVG file which will both highlight the area with a color and also display the name of the region automatically, it works well using the `<object>` tag with HTML but my real problem is just as follows:

```
<path
style="font-size:12px;fill:#d0d0d0"
d="M 442.19,458.85 442.46,458.98 442.7 [.......] "
id="35512"
name="Atlanta, GA "
class="stateA countyB"
onmouseover="displayName('')" />
```

What I need is:

```
<path
style="font-size:12px;fill:#d0d0d0"
d="M 442.19,458.85 442.46,458.98 442.7 [.......] "
id="Atlanta, GA"
name="Atlanta, GA"
class="stateA countyB"
onmouseover="displayName('Atlanta, GA')" />
```

I have tried some rudimentary jQuery and Javascript code, but the problem came with the sheer number of elements and how to change each of them without messing up the order if I used arrays for example. The Id's are not sequential and I assume it would have to be done incrementally.

I could not find a way to get the content of one element, compare with the content of another, change their values, increment the same value to the onmousehover and move on to the next `<path>` element, `getById` would require me to know or use arrays which could still make a mess out of who's what so I'm not really sure

I believe the algorithm would be something along these lines?

```
//document.querySelectorAll("path").forEach(function(item)???
if(Id != Name)
{
  id = name
  onmouseover="displayname('"+Name+"')"
}
```

edit: I am also using the following js scripts to create tooltips which will utilize the displayNames. This option seemed more effective for external SVG use since while being external it would not be able to output data to the page

```
<text class="tooltip" id="area-name" x="10" y="650" visibility="hidden"> </text>

<script type="text/ecmascript"><![CDATA[
    // set trigger for tooltip
    var tooltip = document.getElementById('area-name');
    var triggers = document.getElementsByClassName('county');
    for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
        triggers[i].addEventListener('mousemove', showTooltip);
        triggers[i].addEventListener('mouseout', hideTooltip);
    }
    function showTooltip(evt) {
        tooltip.setAttributeNS(null, "visibility", "visible");
    }
    function hideTooltip(evt) {
        tooltip.setAttributeNS(null, "visibility", "hidden");
    }

    // tooltip area name
    function displayName(name) {
        document.getElementById('area-name').firstChild.data = name;
    }
]]>
```

Comment: there is syntax rules for id values, one of them is banning space character; otherwise the principle of an id is to serve as a unique identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the [EventTarget.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) function instead of manipulating the DOM with all these onmouseover attributes?

If you have the SVG without onmouseover, onmouseleave etc. that would work just fine.

```js
const svg01 = document.getElementById('svg01');
const output = document.getElementById('output');

svg01.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
  // this will replace the displayName() function
  let nameAttr = e.target.attributes['name'];
  if(nameAttr) output.innerHTML = nameAttr.value;
});

function displayName(str) {
  // not in use
}
```

```html
<div id="output">The name will show here</div>
<svg id="svg01" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
<path
style="font-size:12px;fill:#d0d0d0"
d="M 5 5 L 10 5 L 10 10 L 5 10 Z"
id="35512"
name="Atlanta, GA "
class="stateA countyB"
onmouseover="displayName('')" />
</svg>
```

Comment: I use the displayname because the SVG is external and not inline, using tooltips and the display name I can position the string inside the SVG itself which helps the user to visualize since the map is quite big (could be resized but some counties are already tiny). The <div> can only exist outside the limits of the SVG while the tooltip stays inside, it has its pros and cons but works better in my opinion